# How to programmatically select a list item?

Tags: android

I want to create a dialog similar to the one found in Gmail client Settings->General Settings->Auto-Advance (can't attach a picture, but it is a simple radio button selector with 3 items). I can't seem to find any way to set a selected item from the code, nor to retrieve an index of currently selected item; it always returns -1. Manual selection works OK. I tried using

```
listView.setSelection(position);
```

wrapping it into Runnable didn't help either. Any ideas?

Comment: Check https://abhik1987.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/android-alert-dialog-with-single-choice-item-selection-implementation/

Comment: @JaiSoni. Thanks, that's the way I've built the dialog too. (~~They don't set options from the code though~~ scratch that, they do, it is in setSingleChoiceItems, I haven't noticed) and assume using local variable to store selection result, which I wanted to avoid, because it is clearly there already. listItem.getCheckedItemPosition() is the way to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

i came across the same problem..in my case i make the first list view value as blank and i did everything u did from the second element of the list..

```
new String[]{//this is my list view

                    getString(R.string.blank),
                    getString(R.string.Trans_Detail),
                    getString(R.string.Trans_Summary),
                    getString(R.string.Logout),
            }));
```

clickListener:

```
 public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Intent intent;
    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:

            break;
        case 2:
            intent = new Intent(TransDetail.this, TransSummary.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 3:
            intent = new Intent(TransDetail.this, LogOut.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
```

by making this i skipped the auto returns -1
this is not the exact code..but u can get some idea for ur code

Answer (score 0):

OK, should've been using

```
listView.setItemChecked(position, boolean)
```

and

```
listView.getCheckedItemPosition()
```

instead.